# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RegisterPage -> PostProvider]: how to resolve?

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I already tried, but I can not post my code here
if you want to put other parts of the code

[register.ts]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4UJt.jpg

[image]

Comment: Did you add RegisterPage declarations in AppModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't all the detail, But I guess that the `PostProvider` not add to `RegisterModule`.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        ...,
        PostProvider
    ]
})
export class RegisterModule {

}
```

Those may solve your error, But may not actually all right for your truly want. You can read [The doc](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your corresponding Module (appModule if only having that one) in `providers` the `RegisterPage injectable, or in your Component providers below`templateUrl: 'register.html`. They both are different in some nuances, but should fix.

Comment: Sorry, I do not speak English, I did not quite understand what you said to me